# Creating a keylogger in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, keylogger

I want to create a simple keylogger in python without any external modules, which will capture every keypress, even when it does not have focus. I have tried using this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import clock, sleep

recorder = Tk()

recorder.config(background="black")

recorder.geometry("1x1+0+0")

recorder.wm_attributes("-alpha",0.01)

recorder.wm_attributes("-topmost",True)

recorder.overrideredirect(True)

def key(event):

if event.char == event.keysym:

    msg = 'Normal Key %r' % event.char

elif len(event.char) == 1:

    msg = 'Punctuation Key %r (%r)' % (event.keysym, event.char)

else:

    msg = 'Special Key %r' % event.keysym

print(msg)

recorder.focus_displayof()

recorder.bind_all('<Key>', key)

recorder.mainloop()
```

but when it loses focus it stops reacting, can someone please help with correct use of recorder.focus_displayof() for example?

Comment: as I know it will not work because operation system doesn't send events to program without focus. Better see [pyHook](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook) (or maybe [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but I'm not sure)

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I want to escape downloading any external modules

Comment: you can have problem because probably you need low-level access to operation system to get keys all time.

Comment: What should I use then? How could I fix it?

Comment: You will  have to use a platform-specific module. Tkinter will only process events it receives, and it only receives events when it has the focus.

Comment: I know only pyHook, [pyKeylogger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pykeylogger/) - you can use it or you can see source code and use the same method.